# Running time: Finding k smallest element using Selection Sort

Tags: algorithm, code-analysis

[image]

I suppose answer is `kn`? But when I try drawing the tree, it looked like

[image]

So I must have done something wrong in the more detailed analysis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your work list has length `k+2` when it should probably have length `k`. My guess is that you meant to run from `n` to `n-(k-1) = n-k+1`.

Now if you want to sum consecutive numbers, the easiest is to remember (or derive) the formula

```
1 + 2 + ... + a = a(a+1)/2
```

Use this to figure out that the sum you're after is

```
n(n+1)/2 - (n-k)(n-k+1)/2 = nk + (k-k^2)/2
```

as you correctly found. Now, think about big O. Since `n>k`, we know `nk > k^2`, so the latter term is really a lower term, and the whole thing is `O(nk)`.